# Block Workerthread by showing a MessageBox in UI (from backgroundworker) in WinForm

Tags: c#

In my little testprogramm I want to check parts of machine, while updating a label and a progress bar on the way (basically a booting form, which informs the user about the progress of the machine start).
For this, I already read about putting stuff in a backgroundworker and updating the UI via ReportProgress. This works fine.

All part checks are done within a do-while-loop, which is only done when the part is checked succesfully. If one part is checked succesfully, the loop is finished and the workerthread moves on to the next loop for the next part until all parts are checked.

Now, in case one part is defective, and is not testing succesfully, I want to Display a MessageBox, informorming the user about the defect. While doing that, the WorkerThread is supposed to stop, waiting for the User to either press Retry or OK. SO far, either press will start the current do-while-loop from the beginning until the problem is fixed.
If I just put a MessageBox.Show("test") in my loop, it shows after the complete backgroundthread is terminated, and starts the background thread again after displaying the message box(es).

Here my code:

```
namespace USBSerialTest
{
public partial class test1 : Form
{
    private int check;
    private int Progress;

    private byte[] Check_byte_Board1 = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x64, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0xed };
    private byte[] Check_byte_Board2 = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x64, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x81, 0xee };

    public test1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shown += new EventHandler(test1_LoadForm);
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);

        //backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += ShowWarning; Not working
    }
    void test1_LoadForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Progress = 0;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Progress, "Checking for Board Function");
        do                                                          //check if Board retruns an error
        {
            Motor.Instance.Check_Board();
            if (Motor.Instance.buf.SequenceEqual(Check_byte_Board1) || Motor.Instance.buf.SequenceEqual(Check_byte_Board2))
            {
                check = 1;
                Progress += 10;
                //MessageBox.Show("test"); not working, just for testing here
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Progress, "Checking for Board Function");

            }
            else
            {
                //here is the important part, when there is an error, I want to display the warning message
                //and start the do-while loop from the start, all other message boxes where just to 
                //test around if the general principle works
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Boarddriver produce Errorcode ... Please Consult");
                if (result == DialogResult.Retry)
                {
                    check = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = 0;
                }
            }
        } while (check != 1);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Progress, "Succes");           
    }
    // Back on the 'UI' thread so we can update the progress bar
    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
        //MessageBox.Show(e.UserState.ToString()); not working
    }

    private static void ShowWarning(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test box"); //not working, displays a Messagebox each time
        //ProgressChanged is triggered, but does not block the worker thread.
    }
}
}
```

So how could I stop the worker thread with a message box warning, and continue it (or redo the current loop)?

Comment: I know this has been asked before in a similar way, thats where I got my "trial solutions" that I played around with. I also read that it is not really approved of to spam the user with MessageBoxes, but I need some user input somehow (only other rough idea would be to change the Label to the warning and display/hide a button when the error event is triggered.

Comment: Your question is very confusing and unclear. With the code you posted, where you call `MessageBox.Show()` from within the `DoWork` event handler, the message box should in fact be shown immediately, and the code should wait at the `Show()` call in the loop until the user has dismissed the message box. That would seem to meet your criteria. Beyond that, it's not clear what your loop is actually doing; it does not seem to execute multiple tests, as your narrative describes, and there does not appear to be any mechanism to restart the tests on failure, based on user input or otherwise.

Comment: Personally, I would not use `BackgroundWorker`. It's a fine class for its time, but it's been superseded by `Task.Run()` and related framework and language features. I'd guess that the best way to address your scenario would be to make your `LoadForm` event handler `async`, use `Task.Run()` to invoke each test, and put all the UI handling directly in the `LoadForm` event handler method. But with such a confusing question, I'm not inclined to try to post a full-fledged answer. Please improve your question if you want one.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thank you for your answer. To clear it up following setup: Microcontroller connected to PC via USB. I adress it with serialport. I send a byte array to the controller (within the Motor class). The controller interprets it (this case it is: "Do your drivers raise an error flag? Yes/No). If the byte array i receive back is translated to a yes, the else case is triggered (if only if the two answer arrays that say no come back). If else is triggered, check is set to 0 and a message box is supposed to display and puts the loop on hold. If you click okay it continues another iteration

Comment: First of all: comments are here for us to ask you for clarification. Your clarification takes the form of editing the question to fix the problem with the post. Second: your comment fails to address any of the issues I noted.

Comment: @PeterDuniho. So the loop is checked until the board error is fixed by the user. I got my code running now though using backgroundworker and instead of a messagebox I change my label to the warning message and show/hide a Retry button. Looks much cleaner anyways in the UI). Show stops the bw, retry buttons set manualresetevent and hides the button, ergo continuing the thread.
To the message box: the times i got it working, it was always executing the task from the backgroundworker twice for some reason. I'll read further into your suggestions, and play around with it, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ReportProgress()` method to report test fail and intercept the issue in `ProgressChanged` event where you can show a message box.

To make the worker thread wait for a user response you can use a synchronisation object for example `AutoResetEvent`.

```
namespace USBSerialTest
{
    public partial class test1 : Form
    {
        private int check;
        private int Progress;
        private MessageBoxResult UserDecision;
        private AutoResetEvent UserDecidedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private string ErrorCode;

        private byte[] Check_byte_Board1 = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x64, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0xed };
        private byte[] Check_byte_Board2 = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x64, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x81, 0xee };

        public test1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Shown += new EventHandler(test1_LoadForm);
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);

            //backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += ShowWarning; Not working
        }
        void test1_LoadForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Progress = 0;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Progress, "Checking for Board Function");
            do                                                          //check if Board retruns an error
            {
                Motor.Instance.Check_Board();
                if (Motor.Instance.buf.SequenceEqual(Check_byte_Board1) || Motor.Instance.buf.SequenceEqual(Check_byte_Board2))
                {
                    check = 1;
                    Progress += 10;
                    //MessageBox.Show("test"); not working, just for testing here
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Progress, "Checking for Board Function");

                }
                else
                {
                    //here is the important part, when there is an error, I want to display the warning message
                    //and start the do-while loop from the start, all other message boxes where just to 
                    //test around if the general principle works
                    ErrorCode = "Boarddriver produce Errorcode ... Please Consult";
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Progress, ErrorCode);

                    UserDecidedEvent.WaitOne();

                    if (UserDecision != DialogResult.Retry)
                    {
                        check = 1;
                        // Rewind checking of the board here to try the same 
                        // action again when calling Motor.Instance.Check_Board()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check = 0;
                    }
                }
            } while (check != 1);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(Progress, "Succes");
        }
        // Back on the 'UI' thread so we can update the progress bar
        void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.UserState == ErrorCode)
            {
                UserDecision = MessageBox.Show("Boarddriver produce Errorcode ... Please Consult");
                UserDecidedEvent.Set();
            }
            else
            {
                progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                label1.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. While the it makes sense to me with the wait I still have two problem when I try to implement the example in my code. First is, that "private MessageBoxResult UserDecision; " does not exist (MessageBoxResult in particular). For following i tried it with DialogResult Userdecision;
2nd is that when I run the code with a simulate defect (disconnected the board) the MessageBox is displayed, but If I press on retry, the backgroundworker starts from the beginning again. and only if I press it a 2nd time it terminates to the end (after fixing the defect)

Comment: To make the worker thread truly retry the last  action you need to somehow tell the `Motor.Instance` object or the `Check_Board()` method to retry it.